# The while and do-while loops The smallest value

Tags: java

I need to write a program that a user inputs a long positive number m. I need to find out what is the smallest int number n such that n! > m.

So far I have written such a code:

```
import java.util.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        long number = scanner.nextLong();
        int fact = 1;
        int count =1;
        while (fact <= number) {
            count ++;
            fact *=count;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Test input:
6188989133
Correct output:
13

Your code output:

My code output is empty. What I am missing here?

Comment: Your code output was empty?

Comment: Yes, my code output is empty

Comment: You are having infinite loop. When you multiply two ints you are also getting `int` value, sometimes *overflowing* to negative one. Change `fact ` type to BigInteger.

Comment: Because you defined `fact` as an `int` and this of course overflows.

Comment: max int value is 2147483647

Comment: I tried this code and the output is empty because the code never terminates...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `long` for the `fact` variable. When you use `int` the possible values are between `-2,147,483,648` and `2,147,483,647`.

However, you will never exceed the input number `6,188,989,133`, so your `while(fact <= number)` loop will never exits. Every integer value possible will be smaller than `6,188,989,133`. This explains why your code output is "empty", as it doesn't reach that `System.out.println(count);` line at all.

Keep in mind that the `long` type has such a limit as well, values can only be between `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808` and `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`. When the input number is that big, you will not find the correct `fact` value which will be greater than the input because you are limited by the `long` type value range. As an example, for the input number `9,000,000,000,000,000,000` (which is inside the `long` type value range) the next factorial number is `51,090,942,171,709,440,000` (the value of `21!`), which is outside the `long` type value range.

You can use the [`java.math.BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class which has an "unlimited" range of possible values and do your math operations on `BigInteger` objects.

Comment: What if user provides max `long` as value? Can `n!` achieve it (in correct amount of iterations)?

Comment: BigInteger was also my first approach, but since result of method for user input in range `20! ... Long.MAX_VALUE` is 21 we can simply handle it with condition like `if(number >= 2432902008176640000L) return 21;` (//then rest of OP code).

Answer (score 0):

`fact` should be declared as `long`. Check the code below:

```
public class TestJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        try{
            
            System.out.println("Input number: ");
               Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
                long number = scanner.nextLong();
                if(number >= 2432902008176640000L) {
                  // log an appropriate message like can not handle 
                  // long value greater than 2432902008176640000L
                   return 21;                       
                }

                long fact = 1;
                int count =1;
                while (fact <= number) {
                    count ++;
                    fact *=count;
                }
                System.out.println("output: "+ count);
            }catch(Exception e){            
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
}
```

**Update (Warning):**

As @Pshemo mentioned, with out the `if condition`,  the above code is fine till 20!, but after that it will cause the infinite loop problem. Hence this condition has to be taken care of. Code has been updated accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately this will fail for user values starting from 20! so >= `2432902008176640000` since correct result for it would be 21 as `21! = 51 090 942 171 709 440 000` but that value exceeds max long and will overflow to `-4249290049419214848` causing loop to iterate more times than it should making result incorrect, or ending (again) in infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks Pshemo, updated the ans based on your useful input.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `fact` type to long